# How to unpublish an app in Google Play Developer Console

Tags: google-play-services, developer-console

I've seen other posts asking the same question with answers that all refer to a giant button that says "Unpublish" on it, which is no longer there (at least as of 2016).

How do you really unpublish an app that is uploaded to the Google Play Developer Console?

Answer (score 425, accepted):

**TL;DR**: (*As of September 2020*) Open the Play Console. Select an app. Select `Release > Setup >Advanced settings`. On the `App Availability` tab, select `Unpublish`.

[image: Setup - Advanced settings]
[image: Unpublish app dialog]
[image: Verify app unpublished]

From https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859350?hl=en&ref_topic=9872026:

> When you unpublish an app, existing users can still use your app and
> receive app updates. Your app won’t be available for new users to find
> and download on Google Play.
>
> #### Prerequisites
>
> - You have accepted the latest Developer Distribution Agreement.
> - Your app has no errors that need to be addressed, such as failing to fill in the content rating questionnaire or provide details about your app's target audience and content.
> - Managed publishing is not active for the app you want to unpublish.
>
> #### To unpublish your app:
>
> Open the Play Console. Select an app. Select `Release > Setup > Advanced settings`. On the `App Availability` tab, select `Unpublish`.

#### How to Disable `Managed publishing`

[image: Managed publishing overview]
[image: Managed publishing toggle dialog]

Comment: It's worth noting that you need to be the application owner (not a listed developer) *AND* the app needs to be set to Standard Publishing, and not Timed Publishing, otherwise 'Unpublish' will be greyed out.

Comment: can you republish it after clicking unpublish??does it require approval again??

Comment: @NateB How do you completely remove it (from the dashboard) ?

Comment: It may take a while for the unpublishing to take effect

Comment: This should not be so damn hard to find. No wonder there are so many abandoned apps still in the Play Store, people can't figure out how to unpublish them.

Comment: Don't forget to scroll down a page and press "Publish update".

Comment: If the app is paid, users who bought it will still have access to it? Even if they uninstall? Thx

Answer (score 84):

In the current version of Google Play store Console  as of(August 2017) here is the procedure of unpublishing your app.

- Choose the app you wish to unpublish.
- Go to **Store presence > Pricing & distribution**.
- You will see "unpublish" button in the app availability section as shown below.
  [image]

After clicking unpublish a dialog will popup confirm and save the changes.

Answer (score 34):

There are two ways to delete an application you have uploaded from the Google Play Developer Console based off of the application's status within the Console. An app's status can be viewed from the "All Applications" tab listed in the furthest column. (See below)

[image]

- **If your app has not yet been published to the Google Play store (ie. Is still a draft):**

Select your app from the list and at the top of the page, underneath your application name, it will say DRAFT in blue with the *super low-profile option to delete it*  just to the right. Observe below:

[image]

Click that and you're done! Keep in mind: *all of the work you have put into this application so far will be deleted from the Google Play Developer Console.*

- **If your app has already been published and you want to remove it from the app store:**

This method is similar, however it should be noted that it is not possible to permanently delete an app from your Developer Console once it has been published to the Play Store.

1. Select the application you would like to publish from the "All Applications" tab on the right of the screen
2. Below the title of the app, similar to how it was with the DRAFT application, there will be *super low-profile text* allowing you the option to unpublish your app from the Play Store. This process "may take a few hours to complete" as it is said by the Developer Console.

I hope this helps to answer some people's questions.

Comment: Note: It says "Delete" but they mean unpublish.

Answer (score 27):

1. Go to your "play.google.com" dashboard
2. Select your app
3. In left menu item select "Store presence"
4. Then, select "Pricing & distribution"
5. Click "Unpublish" in "App Availability" section

Answer (score 24):

Click on Store Listing and then click on 'Unpublish App'.

[image: See image for details]

Comment: If I unpublish, then later can i just publish again (same apk)? or i have to wait or rewrite all infos?

Comment: You can publish again whenever you want.

Answer (score 15):

Go to "Pricing & Distribution" and choose "Unpublish" option for "App Availability", please refer below youtube video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaH3X8ZD-l8

Answer (score 13):

The new version is hard to find. Select the app, then look for "3 dot menu" in upper right corner.
[image]

Answer (score 10):

If you are facing error during Unpublish the application in your **Google Play Consol**, just follow these 2 steps and its done.

The Error:[image]

**Solution:**

**1st step:** On the left panel, click **Publishing overview** -> **Manage**, then change the Managed publishing status to **Managed publishing off**.

Example: [image]

**2nd step**: Now goto **Setup**->**Advanced Setting**->**App availability**.

Now you can able to click the **Unpublished** option.

Example:

[image]

**Thanks for reading.**

Answer (score 5):

As per new Interface follow these steps

1. Go to Google Play Developer Console
2. Select your app you want to un-publish
3. From the left Navigation **Release** >> **Setup** >> **Advance Settings**
4. In the **App Availability**  Check on **Unpublished** Radio button
   [image]

Comment: Actually because of Google Play Console beta update, this is the updated answer... Thanks.

Comment: You are most welocme

Answer (score 2):

As per recent version.
You need to go advanced settings.  In this section you will find the un-publish button.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, they've updated the Google Play developer page again.  Now, at the far right, click the vertical ellipsis (like a colon with an extra dot in it).  That now has the 'Unpublish App' option.

Answer (score 1):

**To unpublish your app on the Google Play store:**

1. Go to https://market.android.com/publish/Home, and log in to your Google Play account.
2. Click on the application you want to delete.
3. Click on the Store Presence menu, and click the “Pricing and Distribution” item.
4. Click Unpublish

Comment: and is it deletable once we're in unpublished status?

Comment: We can't delete it yet unfortunately