# Unpublish app button doesn't work

Tags: android, google-play, publish-actions, google-developers-console

I couldn't understand why the 'Unpublish app' button in Google's Developer Console isn't available (I can see it, but not press it).

[image: Example of how it looks like]

It looks as if the link is disabled.

```html
<a class="gwt-Anchor gux-disabled" disabled="">Unpublish app</a>
```

Anyone has any idea why is it so?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846872/how-to-unpublish-an-app-in-google-play-developer-console

Comment: Martin, I looked at that link before asking my question. The button used to unpublish the app isn't working. I can't press it.

Answer (score 25):

You have turned on manage publishing that’s why your button is not working
You have to turn the manage publish off. Then this button will work.
For more you can see this solution video
https://youtu.be/EaH1Ls04uK8

Comment: That's the correct answer for the new Google Play Console

Answer (score 18):

If the Unpublished button is not working - you have to turn off
the Managed publishing status. See these attached screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

On Google Play Console:

1. Open Publishing Overview tab. If Managed Publishing turned on, then turn it off by clicking the 'Manage' button.
2. Now you can open Advanced Settings and unpublish the app by choosing the 'Unpublished' switch. Don't forget to Save changes.

That's it ))

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because the app is still being distributed. It takes a couple of hours for the app to the released. This depends on the localisation of the app. if you left this default, the app will be distributed worldwide.

According to Android Authority:

> It takes a few hours for the app to appear. The publication process
>   is automatic and it isn’t too long before your app becomes available
>   for download.

Wait for a bit and try again.  It also seems very wierd from Google, however the label has a grey color, making it seem unavailable. In fact it would be available, when clicking on it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I don't think that is the issue. The app is distributed for a long time. It is available on Google Play, but not like every other app in my console, this one I cannot unpublish.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you cant un-publish an app that is being used. Or after more than 24 hours of publishing.

This is to stop you un-publishing an app that someone has purchased etc.

I had to contact their support team to remove one of my apps. And they something similar to the above (which criteria i met as only I had installed it), so were able to remove it for me.

Contact support for more help / advice on the issue, specific to the app you wish to remove.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've contacted the support team. hope for an explanation in the near future. 
Btw, the app doesn't have any "strings attached" (no in-app payments and stuff like that).