# How do I remove (unpublish) my app from Play Store?

Tags: google-play

Every tutorial, example and even official google description is deprecated. The new layout does not have the feature button at the described position.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: As per new Interface follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63340125/8663316

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unpublish an app in Google Play Developer Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846872/how-to-unpublish-an-app-in-google-play-developer-console)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**: (*As of September 2020*)
Open the Play Console. Select an app. Select `Release > Setup >Advanced settings`. On the `App Availability` tab, select `Unpublish`.

[image: Setup - Advanced settings]
[image: Unpublish app dialog]
[image: Verify app unpublished]

From https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859350?hl=en&ref_topic=9872026:

> When you unpublish an app, existing users can still use your app and
> receive app updates. Your app won’t be available for new users to find
> and download on Google Play.
>
> #### Prerequisites
>
> - You have accepted the latest Developer Distribution Agreement.
> - Your app has no errors that need to be addressed, such as failing to fill in the content rating questionnaire or provide details about your app's target audience and content.
> - Managed publishing is not active for the app you want to unpublish.
>
> #### To unpublish your app:
>
> Open the Play Console. Select an app. Select `Release > Setup > Advanced settings`. On the `App Availability` tab, select `Unpublish`.

#### How to Disable `Managed publishing`

[image: Managed publishing overview]
[image: Managed publishing toggle dialog]