# Using the Google Play Developer API to unpublish an app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api, google-play-console

Couldn't find anything on this -

Does anyone know if it's possible to *unpublish* and existing app from google play using the developer API? I understand you can make updates to the description/upload a new version/etc via the [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/) but I couldn't find anything anything bout the published status.

Situation is I have a set of apps that are being published, and from time to time they'd need to be de-listed/unpublished. I'm looking for a way to have this done without needing to manually do it via the developer console.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this answer might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45466377/9464051

Comment: Thanks! Something I'd already known. I was hoping to be able to accomplish this via the API.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this functionality does not exist.

Out of curiousity, can you explain why you'd want to unpublish programatically? Unpublishing is usually a rare event in the lifecycle of an app. If you need to do it regularly, either we have missed a use case, or you are doing something which could possibly be accomplished better another way. I'd love to hear more details why you'd want this - either in a comment or a personal message.

Comment: The apps are published as part of a service, so I was hoping to be able to have the app un-published programmatically as part of the normal process we'd go through when closing an account.

The use case wouldn't be massive, was wondering out of convenience vs manually unpublishing (which doesnt take long)

Comment: Thanks, as you say this sounds like a fairly edge case. I'll feed it in to product managers though

Comment: Awesome, thanks! 

It was mostly convenience, like I said, not necessity. So more 'Oh this would be awesome if it could happen!' but isn't going to break the bank if it cannot either.