# How can I unpublish an app from production and republish beta in google play without creating a new app?

Tags: android, google-play, release, beta

I first accidentally uploaded an APK to production in the google play developer console.

So I generated a new apk with higher version code and published it in beta channel as **Open Beta Testing** so it will listed in play store as **Early Access** .

Now when I click publish, it actually publishes my app to the play store, even though I have now uploaded to the **Beta** channel. There is not intimation that app is in early access.

It behaves like production release.

There is no way to delete the production APK.

The unpublish option in console will unpublish the whole app ..There is no option to unpublish production alone.

I hope I don't need to delete the whole app project from google play?

**My Steps** 
I searched many questions in Stackoverflow like my question about Google play issues. They suggested to create an new app with different package name.
*(This is not a duplicate question)*

But I don't want change my package because I registered the package name with many API providers and backend providers  (like Firebase , Fabric)

And we like the package name very much.

And the old questions in SOF is pretty outdated. So I want to know any changes happened in google policy.

Comment: You can't do this. Just go to app release and add new apk to beta release

Comment: Yes. I added a new apk in beta release .. But it goes to producation

Comment: No if you upload build in beta it will show option to join beta program for your app and if user join the beta program they can download your beta app.

Comment: @RutvikBhatt ..How can I publish my app in PLAY STORE public listing as beta app ..

Comment: I want to get this intimation "This app is in development. It may be unstable." in play store

Comment: Have you solved your problem. I have also this problem, please help

Answer (score 1):

You can unpublish the app and wait to publish app in right time.
[How to unpublish an app in Google Play Developer Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846872/how-to-unpublish-an-app-in-google-play-developer-console)

I am not sure if this will affect closed tests etc., but I don't think so

Comment: That unpublish option will unpublish the whole app ..There is not option to unpublish production alone

Comment: Ahh right. Then you will have to unpublish whole app and create new project just for testing then. After testing publish it again in this project so you will keep the package name

Answer (score 1):

Once you have published in production, you always have to have a production APK. You can't unpublish in production and still have a version in beta.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to unpublish the production app at : Store Presence > Pricing & Distribution > App Availablity > Unpublish. After the unpublish of the app at production - my app continues to available at internal test/beta distribution.

Comment: You app would be available for already downloaded users, not for new users.