# Delete app from Play Store that was disabled

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I got the following problem:

I published an app that had to do with Corona. I didn't know that Google doesn't allow this (unless it's approved by your government in some way), so Google disabled the app directly.

I have tried to just delete it then, so it doesn't appear in the Dashboard anymore, but I couldn't find how to do this. I've searched the internet on how to delete disabled apps and it seems like that is not possible.

Now that would be fine, but there's the following issue:
Since it was disabled, Google Admob says "one of my apps violates the terms of use of Admob". There also isn't a direct problem with that, but Admob just sent me an E-Mail yesterday that says

> Google will introduce a new strike-based system to enforce against advertisers who repeatedly violate Google Ads policies

So I need to remove the App. How can I do that?!

---

Here's a screenshot that shows that everything is greyed out and therefore I cannot delete the app the normal way:

[image]

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but I think it's because you just have to search the internet for a simple (How do I remove this app ..?) And it tells you that you can't do it, explaining that at most you can cancel the publication on the Play Store, or hide it also on AdMob, but you cannot delete an app published on the Play Store or linked on AdMob.

Comment: My advice is: unpublish on PlayStore and contact AdMob (I don't know if you will be able, but with a disabling problem I think so) explaining what happened.

As for the email I received it too as I think everyone. It does not have to do with disabling the account but is simply a message sent to tell you that the policies will change, as they do so many times.

Comment: I don't see a way to cancel something in the Play Store. And I cannot delete it on Admob because I have several apps published that use the same App-ID in Admob. And as said, I have searched the internet and what I've found is indeed that it seems impossible to do. But first, the answers are some years ago and things change. Especially things change when Google introduces a new strike system. So I don't see why this question isn't valid. I think it's very important.

Comment: Here you can find how to remove the app from the publication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846872/how-to-unpublish-an-app-in-google-play-developer-console
As for downvotes, maybe next time you say that you know it can't be done from what you've been looking for but you're asking if things have changed.
Because otherwise it may seem that you are just someone who does not want to search, which it seems you are not.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but that doesn't work because as said, everything is greyed out. I cannot click on "Advanced Settings" nor on anything else. I have edited and added a screenshot

Comment: Ah well yes rightly having removed them it would be useless for you to do it too.
Have you tried to contact support?
I ask you because if it is as you said I think the appeal will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it unfortunately. The only thing you can do is fix the problem and only then delete it.

Comment: Okay, but how can I fix the problem? I'm not allowed to change the app name or the APK, it's all greyed out. The only thing I can do is submit an appeal that I think they made a mistake.

Comment: Only google can fix. You can explain your reasons!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by select app and then setup option > Advance setting  here you can unpublish and more setting with you app

Comment: Sorry, can you please elaborate? Which options should I click?

Comment: At Google play console > From application dashboard click on "Setup" and then Advance setting and Unpublish